# Yii: Calling afterRender() after renderPartial()

Tags: php, yii, render, renderpartial

`afterRender()` controller method invokes after `render()`, but not after`renderPartial()`.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling renderPartial, save return result and call afterRender this way:

```
$view = 'myView'; // etc
$output = $this->renderPartial($view, array(...));
$this->afterRender($view, $output);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it regularly, override `renderPartial` in a `CController` class and call `afterRender` in there.